# gdb vector attempt to take address not located in memory

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, gdb

I have a vector, `vector<int> myvecotr`. assume that `myvector={p1,p2,p3,p4}`, I need to read `(p1, p2), (p2,p3),(p3,p4)`.

```
int t1,t2;
for(vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end();++it){
   t1=*it;
   t2=*(it+1);   // the question is here ?
}
```

when I debug it using gdb,

```
(gdb) p *(it+1)
(gdb) Attempt to take address not located in memory
```

so, my question is, why `*(it+1)`,sometimes, doesn't work, but `++it` works?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *why *(it+1),sometimes, doesn't work, but ++it works* define (doesn't) work

Answer (score 6):

This is just a [gdb bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16180), nothing more.

Comment: What that means? gdb bug

Comment: It means that you aren't doing anything wrong.  gdb just has a bug that prevents it from evaluating that expression.